# I cannot understand the usage of Descriptor

Tags: assembly, nasm

the declaration:

```
%macro Descriptor 3
dw  %2 & 0FFFFh             
dw  %1 & 0FFFFh             
db  (%1 >> 16) & 0FFh           
dw  ((%2 >> 8) & 0F00h) | (%3 & 0F0FFh) 
db  (%1 >> 24) & 0FFh           
%endmacro
```

the usage:

```
DA_DRW      EQU 92h

LABEL_GDT:         Descriptor    0,              0, 0         
LABEL_DESC_TEST:   Descriptor 0500000h,     0ffffh, DA_DRW
LABEL_DESC_VIDEO:  Descriptor  0B8000h,     0ffffh, DA_DRW
```

I just started to study nasm yesterday, and please answer it a little detailed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A macro amounts to compile-time text substitution. In this case you've got a macro named `Descriptor` which takes 3 arguments. Each usage of the macro will be substituted for the macro body, with `%n` being replaced with the n:th argument.

For example:

```
LABEL_DESC_TEST:   Descriptor 0500000h,     0ffffh, DA_DRW
```

Will expand to:

```
LABEL_DESC_TEST: dw  0ffffh & 0FFFFh             
                 dw  0500000h & 0FFFFh             
                 db  (0500000h >> 16) & 0FFh           
                 dw  ((0ffffh >> 8) & 0F00h) | (DA_DRW & 0F0FFh) 
                 db  (0500000h >> 24) & 0FFh
```